# AVR C - Why inverting values?

Tags: port, avr, inverse

I have extremly stupid question, but I wasn't able to find answer to it. I am starting AVR programming and I have one question, regarding code example I've found.

```
int main(void)
{
    DDRA = 0xFF; // Setting all port A pins for output

for(;;)
{
    PORTA = ~0x21; // Why ~ if we want PA0 and PA5 to be High?
    _delay_ms(10000);
}
```

So why we need to invert 0x21? It should have High on PA0 and PA5, but if we are inverting it, shouldn't it be the opposite (all High except for PA0 and PA5)?

I have tried to search, but I haven't found any explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Where does it say that `PORTA = ~0x21` makes PA0 and PA5 go high?

Comment: This should indeed drive PA0 and PA5 high, with the remaining pins on PORTA driven low. Have you double checked (with an oscilloscope/multimeter) that this truly is what is happening? Perhaps the signals in question expect an active-low input for instance.

Comment: It actualy depends on the scheme - how UC is connected. In my case it was "inversive" way of connection, where "0" meant LED turned on.

I highly appreaciate your help! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you're confusing the pin being high with the LED being on. We often switch the low side of LEDs, because of a tradition formed from some MCUs having higher current sink capacity than source. The inversion would indeed mean the pins are low, but if the LED has its cathode connected to the pin, that's when it is turned on.

Comment: Its also very common for an LED to be switched by a transistor in grounded emitter configuration, which actively inverts the signal as well.

Comment: you can usually sink more than you can source so you will often see that a high (source) on the gpio pin turns the led off and a low (sink) turns the led on.  But you will still see high is on and low is off on some designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with me looking only into code. You should also always check scheme to see how UC is connected.

In my case it was "inversive" way of connection, where "0" meant LED turned on.